# dog cleaning pup way too much

Tags: dogs, behavior

My Chihuahua is constantly and I do mean constantly licking her pups genitals, not his rear but his other part and she doesn't seem to lick anywhere else!

Comment: Please be more specific with your question, as it stands it isnt a question, and if it were it's too broad.

Comment: Is it possible that they puppies are urinating and the mother is cleaning it up?